# Invalid Escape Sequence in Java

Tags: java, string

When I create this `String`:

```
private String chars = " `~1!2@3#4$5%6^7&8*9(0)-_=+qQwWeErRtTyYuUiIoOpP[{]}\|aAsSdDfFgGhHjJkKlL;:'"zZxXcCvVbBnNmM,<.>/?";
```

Eclipse tells me:

```
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\` is an escape character. You're basically escaping `|` which doesn't need to be escaped at all. If you want to represent an `\` in String, then you need to let it escape itself.

```
private String chars = " `~1!2@3#4$5%6^7&8*9(0)-_=+qQwWeErRtTyYuUiIoOpP[{]}\\|aAsSdDfFgGhHjJkKlL;:'\"zZxXcCvVbBnNmM,<.>/?";
```

Please note that the `"` **does** need to be escaped, otherwise the string value ends too early and the code still won't compile due to all the odd characters thereafter.

Comment: I actually did when I pasted it, but for some reason, StackOverflow took it out. Here it is one more time:

" `~1!2@3#4$5%6^7&8*9(0)-_=+qQwWeErRtTyYuUiIoOpP[{]}\|aAsSdDfFgGhHjJkKlL;:'\"zZxXcCvVbBnNmM,<.>/?";

Comment: BalusC's answer is right, @Cg2916. You need to escape the backslash as well as the quotation mark. Neither your comment nor your pastebin have the backslash escaped.

Comment: As answered, you've an `\|` which is not a valid escape sequence. You need to let the \ escape itself to represent it as-is, thus so: `\\|` like as in my answer. The `\"` is just additional hint.