# System.setProperty: Invalid Escape Sequence

Tags: java

Im trying to make a reference to a bin.

```
System.setProperty("mbrola.base", "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\FreeTTS\MBrola Project");
```

But Im getting this error:

```
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )
```

Comment: You can use File.separator too. It will give you platform independent file separator

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid Escape Sequence in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612270/invalid-escape-sequence-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want actual backslashes, which are usually part of escape sequences.  You must escape the backslashes themselves, with another backslash.

```
System.setProperty("mbrola.base", "C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\FreeTTS\\MBrola Project");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because this isn't a valid string literal:

```
"C:\Users\Name\Desktop\FreeTTS\MBrola Project"
```

You need to escape the backslashes:

```
"C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\FreeTTS\\MBrola Project"
```

The string itself will only have the single backslashes though - you're *just* escaping it in source code.